# How can I stream 360 videos on my site from Azure Media service blob?

Tags: video, azure-storage, 360-degrees

How can I stream 360 videos on my site? My mp4 videos are stored on my Azure Media Services blob and I use an adobe flash player on my site. I'm not sure where and what to add so the 360 feature works. I want it to stream on my site from Azure just like they do it here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1HPy70D048Y

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to find a video player that can specifically handle that kind of video. The default HTML5 video player does not.

A quick search showed me a few options, such as the [Kolor Eyes player.](http://www.kolor.com/kolor-eyes/)

Get that player onto your page, and simply point the player's source (src) so that it points towards the address where your blob storage is located for the .mp4.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Dave I had spoken to them one month ago. there is no way to put the player on my site. The way they work is that I need to upload the video file into their site/server. Only then I can get a iframe code to embed it onto my site. They offer 3 options for us to post the video: public, unlisted or private. With the unlisted I was able to hide my video from their site page http://eyes.kolor.com/ and use the iframe on my player/site http://goo.gl/CXAnjC .That is ok but the reason I wrote and did not want to use a service like that was because I wanted to use my own player which has my site logo, not theirs. Therefore I wanted to see if Azure will be able to do the 360 encoding so it can use my own Azure server blob and add whatever extension is needed to my player that Azure would require... that's what I was looking forward to find out what extensions I need for my player and Azure encoding capabilities ;)

Comment: OK, I understand now. Yeah, you need to either find a 360 player or write your own. Either way, Azure can stream the video to it. 

I suppose because it is still such a new technology, you may have a difficult time finding a player.

Comment: btw the Kolor people gave me a list to contact if I need a custom player...will go that road then. Thanks I just needed to know if Azure had to do some kind of special encoding to work with the player....  guess not, the by your answer its all on the player. Thank you ;)

Comment: This should have been a comment to the other answer you're referring to. This is not a proper stand alone answer.